# How to save/submit an InfoPath SharePoint 2010 Form library data into SQL database

Tags: infopath, forms-services

I have an InfoPath form template created from a custom schema. This template is hosted in SharePoint 2010 InfoPath form library. I want to store the data in InfoPath form library so that I can use workflows, content types and other goodies that SharePoint provides. However, as the user is saving data into the Forms library, I want the same data that be saved in my special SQL database so that I can utilize the data for Corporate Data Warehousing jobs. Is ther a way to do this? 
I know that if I had constructed my InfoPath form template based on SQL database fields i.e. as opposed to my custom schema, then I would be able to submit the data directly into my SQL database. But that is not what I want.

Please advise.

Sincerely

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can't submit to the database directly. You need to expose your database through web services where the create/update/delete are implemented. Then on your InfoPath form you can add a connection to this web service to add data to your database.

Answer (score 0):

Add your SQL table as an external content type with use of BCS. Then you'll have your SQL table as a list, and from your workflow you can use this list just as a normal sharepoint list. Update, Create etc.