# Is there any way to store InfoPath form's data in SQL server tables without code?

Tags: infopath

Is there any way to store Infopath form data in SQL server tables without code?

I am using InfoPath 2010 (with repeating tables) and saving `.xml` form in SharePoint forms library.

I am using SharePoint 2010.I want to save form's data in SQL to generate reports in future.

Please suggest possible solutions.I can not go for the coding approach.

Any solution with SSIS, BCS or web service is fine for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Business Connectivity Services** (BCS) is the way to store list data to SQL.

For complete implementation check:

[Link1](http://go.limeleap.com/community/bid/289541/Creating-InfoPath-Forms-that-Save-to-SQL-Server-Database) , 
[Link 2](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2010/01/18/sp-2010-getting-started-with-business-connectivity-services-bcs-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx) , 
[Link 3](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18646/how-to-save-submit-an-infopath-sharepoint-2010-form-library-data-into-sql-databa) , 
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558778.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Form library forms are not stored in SQL and the format they are stored in is full of xml so you have little or no hope of reporting on them. The only way to report on Sharepoint data using SSRS is to use either external content lists (ECTs) and report on the external tables or you can use Sharepoint Custom lists which are also wrapped in xml but we use [SQList by Axioworks](http://www.axioworks.com/sqlist) to clean that xml. It basically copies/updates (every few seconds) all of the SP lists to a new table without the xml. Then you can report on that nice clean data.